# Kotlin: CoroutineScope is collecting data even after flow is cancelled

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-paging, kotlin-flow

I am trying to launch an `Coroutine` inside my `PagingSource` in order to watch how long my paging source is already trying to get my data. The only problem I have here is, that my `Coroutine` is still somehow collecting some data, even after I stopped my `shopPagingWatcher Flow`. Because of this, it `throws IOException("No Intenet Exception)` even when it should not.

I am launching a `Coroutine` because watching the state should not block the main flow of my `paging source`

### PagingSource

```
class ShopRemoteMediator @Inject constructor(
    private val db: FirebaseFirestore,
    private val shopPagingWatcher: ShopPagingWatcher,
) : PagingSource<QuerySnapshot, Product>() {

    @InternalCoroutinesApi
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<QuerySnapshot>): LoadResult<QuerySnapshot, Product> {
        return try {
            // Launch Async Coroutine, Observe State, throw IO Exception when not loaded within 5 seconds
            shopPagingWatcher.start()
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                shopPagingWatcher.observeMaxTimeReached().collect { maxTimeReached ->
                    if (maxTimeReached) {
                        Timber.d("Mediator failed")
                        throw IOException("No Internet Exception")
                    }
                }
            }

            val currentPage = params.key ?: db.collection(FIREBASE_PRODUCTS)
                .limit(SHOP_LIST_LIMIT)
                .get()
                .await()

            val lastDocumentSnapShot = currentPage.documents[currentPage.size() - 1]

            val nextPage = db.collection(FIREBASE_PRODUCTS)
                .limit(SHOP_LIST_LIMIT)
                .startAfter(lastDocumentSnapShot)
                .get()
                .await()

            // When PagingSource is here, it successfully loaded currentPage and nextPage, therefore stop Watcher
            Timber.d("Mediator Sucessfull")
            shopPagingWatcher.stop()

            LoadResult.Page(
                data = currentPage.toObjects(),
                prevKey = null,
                nextKey = nextPage
            )

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // IOException should be caught here, but it is not! The app crashed instead!
            Timber.d("Mediator Exception ist $e")
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

### ShopPagingWatcher

```
@Singleton
class ShopPagingWatcher @Inject constructor() : Workwatcher()
```

### Abstract WorkWatcher

```
abstract class Workwatcher {
    private companion object {
        private val dispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
        private var timeStamp by Delegates.notNull<Long>()

        private var running = false
        private var manuallyStopped = false
        private var finished = false

        private const val maxTime: Long = 5000000000L
    }

    // Push the current timestamp, set running to true
    // I don't know if it is necessary to use "synchronized"
    @InternalCoroutinesApi
    fun start() = synchronized(dispatcher) {
        timeStamp = System.nanoTime()
        running = true
        manuallyStopped = false
        finished = false
    }


    // Manually stop the WorkerHelper 
    // I don't know if it is necessary to use "synchronized"
    @InternalCoroutinesApi
    fun stop()  = synchronized(dispatcher) {
        running = false
        manuallyStopped = true
        finished = true
        Timber.d("Mediator stopped")
    }

    // Function that observes the time
    fun observeMaxTimeReached(): Flow<Boolean> = flow {
        // Check if maxTime is not passed with → (System.nanoTime() - timeStamp) <= maxTime
        while (running && !finished && !manuallyStopped && (System.nanoTime() - timeStamp) <= maxTime) {
            emit(false)
            Timber.d("Currenttime is smaller, everything fine")
        }
        // This will be executed only when the Worker is running longer than maxTime
        if (!manuallyStopped && !finished) {
            Timber.d("Currenttime bigger, yikes. Stop worker")
            emit(true)
            running = false
            finished = true
            return@flow
        } else if (finished || manuallyStopped) {
            return@flow
        }
    }.flowOn(dispatcher)
}
```

How should I change my `Coroutine` inside my `PagingSource` in order to achieve my goal? `Timber.d("Mediator stopped)` gets called.

I appreciate every help, thank you.

Comment: You haven't really cancelled the flow.  You have to cancel the coroutine that is collecting the flow, meaning cancelling the Job returned from launch.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I don't understand. I have stopped my flow with `shopPagingWatcher.stop`. Wouldn't that mean, that my flow is cancelled?

Comment: No.  Flows aren't really things that _can_ be stopped, only collections of flows can be stopped.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Then what does my `stop()` function do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to measure duration? Time is already passing everywhere, you don't need another thread or coroutine to track that. There's `measureNanoTime {}` that measures how long a code block took to execute.

Do you need to apply a timeout inside a suspending function? There's `withTimeout` exactly for that. Example:

```kotlin
class ShopRemoteMediator @Inject constructor(
    private val db: FirebaseFirestore,
    private val shopPagingWatcher: ShopPagingWatcher,
) : PagingSource<QuerySnapshot, Product>() {

    @InternalCoroutinesApi
    override suspend fun load(
        params: LoadParams<QuerySnapshot>
    ): LoadResult<QuerySnapshot, Product> {
        return try {
            withTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) {         // <<<<<<<<<<
                val currentPage = ...
                val nextPage = ...
                LoadResult.Page(
                    data = currentPage.toObjects(),
                    prevKey = null,
                    nextKey = nextPage
                )
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        } catch (e: TimeoutCancellationException) {    // <<<<<<<<<<
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will serve my problem. But I get an error using `withTimeout`, it says "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied"

Comment: Sorry, I made the example from my head. Maybe withTimeout only has one argument, milliseconds, without the TimeUnit. Check the IDE suggestions.

Comment: Okay, it works now. But do you maybe have a solution for my first problem as well? How should I call a Coroutine so that it will be executed asynchronously?